# getting state object from react UI on spring without create model

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am a newbie in react and spring, trying to get print simple state data on my spring boot console without making model.

react code:It works fine and shows output as data: "{"user":{"username":"foo","password":"bar"}}".

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import LoginBtn from "../Buttons/ActionButtons/LoginActionBtn";
import Username from "../CommonInputElement/Username";
import Password from "../CommonInputElement/Password";
import Axios from "axios";

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.inputUsernameRef = React.createRef();
    this.inputPasswordRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = this.state;

    Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user", { user }).then(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { username } = this.state;
    const { password } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login-form">
          <p>Login Form</p>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Username
              inputRef={this.inputUsernameRef}
              value={username}
              name="username"
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <Password
              inputRef={this.inputPasswordRef}
              value={password}
              name="password"
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <div className="home-button-container btn-group">
              <LoginBtn />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Spring code:It is the problem where it returns null. Can anyone help me about fetching react state object on spring without creating model or repositories?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@RequestParam Map<String, String> data) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(data.get("username"));
        return data.toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I will explain the problem, in your react code you are sending a data as a `body` but trying to consume that as a `param` in spring boot.

I will just rewrite th axios request and spring consumer part alone.

And also from what I could while sending the data to backend you don't really need to wrap the simple name and password in another object so consider the below format.

#### Request Format

```
{
  "username":"foo",
  "password":"bar"
}
```

#### React Code

```
    const payload = this.state;  // {"username":"foo","password":"bar"} inspect the request in browser
    Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user", payload).then(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
```

### Back End

Spring can map the request object directly as a pojo using `@RequestBody`, so create a class.

#### User.class

```java
public class User {

  private String username;
  private String password;

  // Getter & Setter
}
```

#### Controller

Add the `User.class` as the `RequestBody`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@RequestBody User user) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        return user.getUsername();
}
```

## EDIT - With Param

#### React Code

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user", null, { params: payload}).then(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
```

#### Back end

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(username);
        return username;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't wish to have a pojo class to handle those request. By the way I have found some solution like-

'let user = new FormData();user.append("username", this.state.username);user.append("password", this.state.password);

Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/user", user).then(res => {console.log(res);console.log(res.data);});'

and in spring-
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",  method = RequestMethod.POST)public String addEmployee(@RequestParam Map<String, String> data) throws ParseException {System.out.println(data.get("username"));return data.toString()}